# About android surfaceview screenshot

Tags: android

I'm using the surfaceview playback network video, and I want to implement the screenshot function of video.
But I found a lot of data and there was no way to solve the screenshot problem.
This functionality cannot be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take screenshot of any view, try this:

```
view.buildDrawingCache(); //optional if drawing cache is enabled.
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```